# Forces applied to bucket

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, pressure, fluid-statics

We have two similar buckets of equal weight submerged in water, the first up and the second down.

1. Calculation of the weight of each bucket (Can the weight of the water inside each bucket be considered an additional weight, or can it be considered in one case without the other)
2. Are the forces applied to each bucket the same?

[image]

Comment: @Eyyboss Buoyancy depends on water displacement, not pressure difference.

Comment: Question 2 is ambiguous.  Can you add more detail?

Comment: @AdrianHoward I said it arises due to pressure difference. It does depend upon the water displaced but if the fluid vessel was placed in a place with no gravity (hence no vertical pressure variation in the fluid), there would be no upthrust.

Comment: @Eyyboss I think we have to assume there is gravity. As far as the pressure difference between the top and bottom of the bucket is concerned, unless it is a very deep bucket the difference shouldn't be much. For approximately every meter in water depth the water pressure increases by about 0.1 atmosphere.

Comment: @AdrianHoward Even if the pressure difference is low, the large area of the base will compensate for it and the force due to pressure difference will be considerable. And we do not have to assume gravity. In absence of any celestial body, the bouyancy will be zero. Please refer to  https://physics.info/buoyancy/summary.shtml#:~:text=Buoyancy%20is%20caused%20by%20differences,since%20pressure%20increases%20with%20depth).

Comment: @Eyyboss Since the question mentions up and down and weight we must assume gravity in this case.

Comment: @AdrianHoward you are right. In this case we have to assume gravity.

Answer (score 1):

IMO there are a number of issues with the wording of the problem.

First, the beginning statement says the buckets are of "equal weight". But part 1 asks to calculate the weight of the bucket. It makes no sense. The true weight of the bucket doesn't change inside or outside the water. It's not clear whether the parenthetical comment is yours or in the problem statement.  Perhaps they're talking about the apparent weight in water(?).

Then, is said that the two buckets are "similar". That is not sufficient to determine the volume of water displaced and thus the buoyant force. You would need to either say they are identical, or that the volume of each bucket is the same which would then mean they have the same density.

Regarding the pressure difference between the top and bottom of each bucket,  assuming these are ordinary size buckets you can probably disregard any water pressure difference between the top and bottom parts of each bucket. In any case, for what it's worth, for approximately every meter in water depth the water pressure increases by about 0.1 atmosphere.

Hope this helps.